# jQuery .html() returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field with the the id "id_email". A user will enter his email into this field on my form.  I am trying to run some validation code on the email that the user inputs. I would like to pass the inputted value to the server to compare it to the database, but jQuery keeps returning a blank string.

HTML:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="id_email" name="email" maxlength="75">
           </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function CheckDuplicateEmail(invalidForm)
{
  $("#id_email").focusout(function()
  {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
             url: "/CheckDuplicateEmail/",
             dataType: "json",
             data: {"email" : $("#id_email").html()},
             success: function(jsonObject) 
             { 
                if (jsonObject === "exists")
                {
                    $("this").append("<ul class=\"errorlist\"><li>This email already exists<li></ul>")
                    invalidForm = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    invalidForm = false;
                }
             }
    });
  });
}
```

When I look at the AJAX post that is being sent to the server, I can see that email is blank.  The line $("#id_email").html() is failing.  I know that the selector is working correctly because the AJAX request is sent to the server. This implies that $("#id_email").focusout is working correctly. Since this statement uses the same selector as the $("#id_email").html() statement, I have to assume the html() function is wrong. Note that I tried the text() function with the same results.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: don't use .html() on an input field, to get the value of the input field use $("#id_email").val() instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$("#id_email").val()`

```
function CheckDuplicateEmail(invalidForm)
{
  $("#id_email").focusout(function()
  {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
             url: "/CheckDuplicateEmail/",
             dataType: "json",
             data: {"email" : $("#id_email").val()},
             success: function(jsonObject) 
             { 
                if (jsonObject === "exists")
                {
                    $("this").append("<ul class=\"errorlist\"><li>This email already exists<li></ul>")
                    invalidForm = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    invalidForm = false;
                }
             }
    });
  });
}
```

You may check out [this post](http://www.tutorialsdesk.com/2012/09/jquery-getting-and-setting-content-text.html) to know more when to use getters like `.html()`, `.val()` and `.text()`

Answer (score 3):

change this line `data: {"email" : $("#id_email").html()},`

to

`data: {"email" : $("#id_email").val()},`

`.html()` will not works for input elements. You need to use `.val()` to get input values.